# how to change the data scraped by facebook like?

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-like

I am using facebook  "like" as a iframe on my site. The data that the facebook button scraps from my sites url is not correct. How can we customize this data being sent or scraped?
 i.e. I am using django, and hence have a base.html which has the meta tags of facebook. This base.html is extented throughout the site. 
Now I cant understand how to customize these meta tags for each individual page that my site has. 
Is there a way to give these attributes in the iframe itself ?

Is the question clear ? else please comment i will make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the open graph meta tags?

http://ogp.me/

I don't think it's valid to add meta tags anywhere in a page (i.e. outside the head tag) in order to customise their contents on each of your pages but I think it's valid in html 5 to have meta tags outside the head tag so I would suggest trying it first and then if you're able to, try and set it up so that in your base.html the meta tags are holding a variable and then on each of your pages that use the base.html you can specify the value of the variable on the individual page.

Comment: Am already doing the variable thing, where the variable used on the particular page are being used. 
But wanted a more elegant solution to it.

Comment: other than facebook scraping the correct information from every page automatically I can't think of anything that is cleaner than having the tags holding a placeholder and then it being customised on each page - doesn't sound so bad to me!